# Environment specific global configuration parameters in CloudBees run@cloud

Tags: cloudbees, paas

It is possible to set global configuration parameters with the `bees config:set -ac account` command, but is it somehow possible to also tell to which environment a global parameter is meant?

For example, I have 2 environments, production and demo. I would like to set database URI parameter to be same for all the app deployments to production environment and another value for it for the demo environment. I can of course set the parameter for each and every application separately, but I have many apps and it would be great having to set it only once as it is the same value for all apps deployed with the same environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

configuration parameters are per application ID, not per account, so you can't get it set once for all your applications. Need to config:set all application you have deployed

Comment: Ok, thanks. Too bad it can't be set per environment. But it's a minor issue anyway.

Answer (score 2):

What I tend to do is have different environments as different applications - this means I can keep them all running (so that means the different environment settings naturally apply when I deploy).

Another idea for a pattern (I haven't used this) - is that where you refer to env vars/system properties that are environment specific, you use a prefix that is another var, that is the env name.

For example

```
DB = System.getProperty(System.getProperty("ENV_NAME") + "_DB");
```

So you can then have environment vars/properties that follow the pattern of:

```
bees config:set -ac blah PROD_DB=<url here>
bees config:set -ac blah DEV_DB=<url here>
bees config:set -ac blah ENV_NAME=DEV #this is the default
```

And then to set a specific environment for an app:

```
bees config:set -a appId ENV_NAME=PROD
```

So whatever you set the ENV_NAME to means it selects what "set" of vars apply.

Just an idea (never used it though).

Comment: if it works well for you - let me know here and I can formally document it !